# Mongo Management Studio has some issues importing text files

Tags: mongodb, text-files

The app: Mongo Management Studio.
The migration is: From MySQL (navicat .txt file exported) to MongoDB.

The structure in text files are different for each collection, I assume that it hasn't be able to parse the file and then the app just hangs, without any further information.

So, any thoughts about it?

The following structure has been used in the text files to use in the "import" feature:

Collection (Table) A:

```
1,Name A,1
2,Name B,1
```

Collection (Table) B:

```
1,1,28c8cb4006e,Name,-10,-30,1
2,1,28ea5bc940029,Name,-10,-30,1
```

Collection (Table) C:

```
399,0,28ea5bc940029,-26.06,-10,0,02/18/2014 22:27:00
400,0,28c8cb4006e,-19.06,-10,0,02/18/2014 22:32:00
```

I'll appreciate any kind of help to make this work, unknowing the required data syntax is quite complicated to correctly use the app, still looking for answers but not being able to find them.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**.
Actually had tried with *.json and *.js files too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you are trying to import the plain text files with the data from sql? Because currently the import only support JSON files with the format of the mongo export.

See the docu for further informations:

https://wiki.litixsoft.de/display/MMS/Import+documents

Comment: Yes indeed, nevertheless I have tried to use both kind of formats, as txt and as json or js. No success yet. And the question was focused on the right syntax that I must use for the correct parsing of the app.

Thanks for the URL 4kochi, very much appreciated.

Comment: You can some hints to the format here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/  Basically it is just JSON. But you have to take care of the data types which are not supported by JSON, like date for example. They have to be formatted (e.g. `"date" : { "$date" : "2014-03-13T13:47:42.483-0400" }`)

Comment: Great, a huge improvement, a clean answer, once again thanks for your time.